# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/runtime/TypeRegistryConfigurerSupplier

Tags: selenium, cucumber-java, serenity-bdd, cucumber-junit, cucumber-serenity

I am getting the 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException' exception while running maven test in my project. The same program works fine if @RunWith is tagged to (Cucumber.class) but apparently not with @Runwith(CucumberWithSerenity.class). I am not sure why issue is appearing!

Note: I did refer the similar post to rectify the issue but apparently none helped me yet.

**Error logs:**

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running foo.boo.TestRunner
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.049 s <<< FAILURE! - in foo.boo.TestRunner
[ERROR] foo.boo.TestRunner.initializationError  Time elapsed: 0.008 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/runtime/TypeRegistryConfigurerSupplier
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.core.runtime.TypeRegistryConfigurerSupplier
[ERROR]   TestRunner.initializationError » NoClassDefFound io/cucumber/core/runtime/Type...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

**TestRunner.java**

```
package foo.boo;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty"},
        features = "foo",
        glue = "boo"
)

public class TestRunner {
}
```

**POM.XML:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>fooboo</groupId>
    <artifactId>Experiment</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20210307</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.29</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-ensure -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-ensure</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.10</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Could someone share what is causing such issues?

Comment: I believe you just use incompatible versions of components.

Comment: @AlexeyR. Can you elaborate please? Are you saying I am using incompatible version in POM.xml file? if yes, can you highlight what needs to be changed?

Comment: For example what is the idea of having `info.cukes:cucumber-core`? As far as I know this package is obsolete..

Comment: @AlexeyR. I did upgrade the package to 7.1.0 version and tried but no luck. I did test by excluding this package as well but still same result!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove all occurences of cucumber artifacts from your pom. Serenity artifacts already have dependencies to the required cucumber versions. The lates supported version is 6.11.

When you put the same artifact of different version to your root pom, you override that. Hence there is version inconsistency take the place.

Answer (score 0):

You should not give space after Scenario. In case of typing something, as follows, will throw an error:
Scenario :
As you see there is a space just before the colon and that throws an error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).